# org-mode: have flycheck resolve relative config while editing code blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, buffer-local

### Desired behaviour

While editing code blocks with `org-mode` by pressing <kbd>C-c '</kbd> I'd like [Flycheck](http://www.flycheck.org/) to resolve relevant configuration
the same way it does for normal files. I'm using JavaScript, and these are `.jshintrc` files within the same ancestry.

To be more specific, I'd like the `.jshintrc` settings to be picked up while editing code if I had my project arranged like this:

```
~/project/file.org
~/project/.jshintrc
```

This doesn't work, but is my ideal behavior.

### Lame solution

The following setup works:

```
~/project/file.org
~/.jshintrc
```

But it's not desirable because it sets defaults across all my projects.

### Possible solutions

I'm not sure if the following solutions are good ideas, and I'm unsure how implement them:

- Set `buffer-file-name` of local buffer when editing source code blocks in `org-mode`.
- Add another function to `flycheck-locate-config-file-functions`.

### Rationale

Looking at the Flycheck source, my "lame solution" works because Flycheck looks at the home directory in case other attempts to look up the configuration fail. This behavior is defined by `flycheck-locate-config-file-functions`.

`flycheck-locate-config-file-ancestor-directories` looks like the function I'd like to succeed in finding the configuration file. It looks like this:

```el
(defun flycheck-locate-config-file-ancestor-directories (filename _checker)
  "Locate a configuration FILENAME in ancestor directories.

If the current buffer has a file name, search FILENAME in the
directory of the current buffer and all ancestors thereof (see
`locate-dominating-file').  If the file is found, return its
absolute path.  Otherwise return nil.

_CHECKER is ignored."
  (-when-let* ((basefile (buffer-file-name))
               (directory (locate-dominating-file basefile filename)))
    (expand-file-name filename directory)))
```

So, if `buffer-file-name` is set to an appropriate value we should be good. So what is its value for my code buffer? `nil`. OK, so what are the effects of setting this variable locally for Org code buffers (and how do I do this whenever I enter from `org-mode` with <kbd>C-c '</kbd>)?

Also, if I add my own look-up function to `flycheck-locate-config-file-functions`, that may solve the problem. But how would I resolve the directory of the current `.org` file from the buffer that lets me edit the JavaScript source?

A simpler solution is welcome as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how you can tell `org-mode` to set `buffer-file-name` to an appropriate value for code buffers:

```el
(defadvice org-edit-src-code (around set-buffer-file-name activate compile)
  (let ((file-name (buffer-file-name))) ;; (1)
    ad-do-it                            ;; (2)
    (setq buffer-file-name file-name))) ;; (3)
```

#### Explanation

<kbd>C-c '</kbd> is bound to `org-edit-special`. According to the documentation (<kbd>C-h f</kbd> `org-edit-special` <kbd>RET</kbd>), this command calls `org-edit-src-code` when point is in a code block. So in order to achieve what you want, you need to [advise](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) `org-edit-src-code` to make it set `buffer-file-name` to the name of the `.org` file that contains the source block you will be editing. **Steps**:

1. Cache name of `.org` file containing source block to edit.
2. Call original function (`org-edit-src-code`).
3. Set `buffer-file-name` to cached file name for code buffer.

---

Based on the research you posted as part of your question, I don't think you need to do anything else to enable Flycheck for code buffers.

Comment: Another solution would be to set `buffer-file-name` in a function of the `org-src-mode-hook`... *if* `org-edit-src-code` wasn't deliberately setting it to `nil` *after* calling `org-src-mode`. Do you know the rationale behind org-src's conviction that `buffer-file-name` should absolutely be nil?

Comment: @T.Verron I have no idea... not sure if I even looked at the source to come up with this answer :)